# Visual Studio 2015 Designer could not be shown

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have this error that appears every time I try to open the designer for my deal class. 
[image]

I've tried rebuilding the solution, cleaning, restarting visual studio to no aid. I have also checked the class itself, if there are any classes above, but this has not fixed the error.

Comment: Your error message clearly and obviously tells you that the problem is because the type/class `IsFixTrader.TraderForm` could not be loaded. Start your trouble-shooting there. Where is this class (and namespace) from? Is it provided by a 3rd-party assembly, or an assembly (class library project) that is part of your VS solution? Can the assembly be found at the location that your project uses to refer to it? Is the assembly file perhaps wrong version or corrupted?  etc...etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this issue was fixed by running as admin and fixing a trader form error, which involved the namespace being incorrect. Silly me.